# pipe(), fork(), and sleep()

Tags: c, fork, pipe

on multiple client request the given server code should respond with a sequential number for each client request. Also for each client request the server should fork a process. the child process then waits for 5 seconds and decrements the client request count. So basically its a token system.

the problem in the code is that when i send multiple client request except the first request others get blocked for 5 seconds which i don't want.

```
static int num = 0;

int main(int ac, char *av[]){

    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    struct hostent *hp;
    char hostname[HOSTLEN];
    int sock_id, sock_fd;
    FILE *sock_fp;
    int pid, fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    sock_id = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock_id == -1)
            oops("Socket");

    bzero((void *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));

    gethostname(hostname, HOSTLEN);
    hp = gethostbyname(hostname);

    bcopy((void *)hp->h_addr, (void *)&saddr.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    saddr.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if(bind(sock_id, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) != 0)
            oops("bind");

    if(listen(sock_id, 5) != 0)
            oops("listen");
    while(1) {
            sock_fd = accept(sock_id, NULL, NULL);
            printf("got a call\n");
            if(sock_fd == -1)
                    oops("accept");

            num++;

            sock_fp = fdopen(sock_fd, "w");
            if(sock_fp == NULL)
                    oops("fdopen");
            fprintf(sock_fp, "Your token number is: %d\n", num);
            fclose(sock_fp);

            pid = fork();

            if(pid == 0){
                    close(sock_id);
                    sleep(5);
                    num--;

                    close(fd[0]);
                    write(fd[1], &num, sizeof(num));
                    printf("Sent: %d\n", num);
                    close(fd[1]);
                    exit(0);
            }
            else if(pid > 0){
                    close(fd[1]);
                    read(fd[0], &num, sizeof(num));
                    printf("Received %d\n", num);
                    close(fd[0]);
                    close(sock_fd);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Your code seems to be missing e.g. a `pipe` call. And what is `sock_id`? And you know that when you close `sock_fp` you also close `sock_fd`?

Comment: i have posted the whole code for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent process, you try to read from an empty pipe, the `read()` will block until data is available, so it blocks until child process wakes up and call `write()`. Write something to the pipe after you call `pipe()`,

```
pipe(fd);
write(fd[1], &num, sizeof(num));
```

it would solve your problem.

And what Joachim Pileborg says about handling reaping of the child processes is important.

Comment: it solved the problem of blocking but created new problems. I sent 3 client request and got the following output:

Comment: it solved the problem of blocking but created new problems. I sent 3 client request and got the following output: in client:
your token number is 1,
your token number is 1,
your token number is 2
in server i got following output:
got a call,
Received 0,
got a call,
Received 1,
got a call,
Received 2,
Sent: 0,
Sent: 1,
sent should have executed 3 times but here its only 2. also sent is not reflecting on shared memory num.

Comment: Since we don't know the execution order of the parent and child processes, the output isn't determinate. And the `read()` or `write()` may fail, you should check the return value. The `num` is not shared by multiple processes, the whole address space is duplicated during `fork()`, parent and child processes have their own copy of the static data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that after the `fork`, in the parent you close both ends of the pipe, so next iteration of the infinite loop you try to use the pipe but it's already closed.

---

You should also handle reaping of the child processes, otherwise they become zombies until the parent process exits. This can be done by installing a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` and in the signal handler call [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html).